# How do I display a PDF thumbnail as a link to the PDF without uploading the image

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails, media

When I found a couple of years ago that WordPress will create thumbnails of uploaded PDFs, I was so happy, thinking I wouldn't have to make and upload separate PDF cover images to have a thumbnail display on my site as the link to a PDF. After some struggle I found that the images created from the uploaded PDFs aren't accessible for display on any public webpage. It seems logical to me that since these files are created when I upload a PDF, I should be able to access them, but this isn't possible. I want to clarify that I don't what to embed the PDF (some are very large), I just want the automatically-generated thumbnail to the be the link to the PDF.

I tried the plugin PDF Thumbnails, but it's clunky at best and it doesn't use the automatically-generated images; it has to create its own.

This seems like such a simple and obvious thing to do so I'm really surprised that this isn't possible "out-of-the-box". If I see the thumbnail in admin, why can't I see it on the live site, too?

The post [Force documents to appear in Featured Image dialogue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368194/force-documents-to-appear-in-featured-image-dialogue) doesn't help me because the Twenty Twenty-three theme doesn't have the typical functions.php file and post-type template files, at least that I can find. I should also note that I am using multisite.

Thanks.

Comment: Untested idea: maybe hook into the upload process from a plugin and create an attachment from the pdf image?  Would need custom programming though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Where are your PDF thumbnails generated? If you can't see them, how do you know you have them?

Comment: Images are stored within the PDF Object `media_details` - example `$value -> media_details -> sizes -> full -> source_url`

Answer (score 0):

The PDF images created by wordpress are stored within the PDF attachment object metadata.

```
[
    {
        "id": 121,
        "media_type": "file",
        "mime_type": "application/pdf",
        ...
        "media_details": {
            "sizes": {
                "full": {
                    ...
                    "source_url": "<domain>/wp-content/uploads/document-name-pdf.jpg"
                }
    }
]
```

### **Extracting the image from the PDF**

Adding an image block or adding a featured image to a post requires an attachment `ID` and not simply a url *probably*

An attachment `ID` can be created by "side loadeding" the `url` into the media library to create an attachement using the `media_sideload_image` function which can return the newly created attachment `ID`

- [Wordpress `media_sideload_image` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/)

### Example

```
$pdf_image_url = $PDF_object -> media_details -> sizes -> full -> source_url;
$attachment_id   = media_sideload_image( 
    $pdf_image_url,
    $post_id, // the post to attach the image 
    'My image title',
    $return_type     = 'id' 
);
$image = set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
```

### Set Post Thumbnail

The function `set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id )` can be used to assign an image to a post as the featured image